# Como sei se uma pacote é dev_dependencies ou dependencies?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tomando como os exemplo deste dois pacotes: freezed e freezed_annotation, a instrução de instalação no site [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages)  é a mesma para os dois pacotes:

[image: freezed]
[image: freezed_anotation]

Porém, em vídeo que mostra como utilizar este pacote é mostrado que `freezed` é `dev_dependencies`:

```
dev_dependencies:
  freezed: ^0.10.6
```

Nem mesmo o [Pubspec Assist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist) que se propões a facilitar a instalação de dependências adiciona o pacote no local correto.

Como sei se uma pacote é `dev_dependencies` ou `dependencies`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies), a regra é simples:

> The rule for deciding between a regular or dev dependency is simple:
>   If the dependency is imported from something in your lib or bin
>   directories, it needs to be a regular dependency. If it’s only
>   imported from test, example, etc. it can and should be a dev
>   dependency.

Explicando a frase acima, você vai colocar em `dev_dependency` apenas aqueles packages que você vai utilizar apenas em testes, exemplos e outras coisas.
Ou seja, você só vai por em `dev_dependency` aqueles packages que você vai utilizar em tempo de desenvolvimento, coisas que não vão importar para uma versão final...

**Exemplo prático**

Um exemplo prático que posso dar é o do MobX:

Colocamos em `dependencies` apenas os packages

```
dependencies:
  mobx:
  flutter_mobx:
```

E em `dev_dependencies`, informamos os packages:

```
dev_dependencies:
  mobx_codegen:
  build_runner:
```

Quando vamos desenvolver nossa aplicação utilizando MobX, precisamos utilizar Widgets e classes do Mobx, para exibir e controlar ações de nossa aplicação, então importamos esse package direto em `dependencies`...

Mas enquanto estamos desenvolvendo, precisamos do `mobx_codegen` e `build_runner` para gerarmos os arquivos `*.g.dart` para auxiliar em nosso desenvolvimento, então apenas inserimos esses packages em `dev_dependencies`.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do **Matheus Ribeiro** está bem escrita e completa. Creio que deva ser considerada como melhor resposta.

Apenas complementando o que foi explicado por ele devido a uma leve ambiguidade (saudável) da pergunta funciona assim:

- Um pacote não possui flag que defina especificamente como sendo `dependencie` ou `dev_dependencie`. Ele é criado para uma finalidade apenas e o modo de criação é o mesmo para ambos.
- Ao decidir utilizar aquele pacote, o desenvolvedor configura o que ele é dentro do seu projeto (Como explicado pelo Matheus). Assim o plugin que citou não tem responsabilidade de determinar se aquele pacote é um ou outro, ele apenas importa, depois disso basta apenas movê-lo para o local correto.

---

**Atualização (10/05/2020)**

O pacote citado na pergunta agora permite que selecione se vai adicionar a lib nas dependências normais ou nas de desenvolvimento. O processo é o mesmo, o que muda é somente que escolherá o local antes de digitar o nome do pacote na pesquisa.

Answer (score 2):

Outra fonte segura é a documentação do pacote (https://pub.dev/), é muito provável que na documentação tenha instruções sobre a instalação do pacote.

[image: site]

Se por acaso não tiver, é só procurar o arquivo `pubspec.yaml` na pasta de exemplo da utilização do pacote no github.